# Where do I find the saved filed mapping I saved in Step 3 of 3 when saving export of participants list?

Tags: civievent

In Find Participants I have selected the fields I would like to export
At Step 3 of £ to give the options to Save the Mapping with a Name and Description which I have done and suggests
"If you want to use the same export setup in the future, check 'Save this field mapping' at the bottom of the page before continuing. You will then be able to reload this setup with a single click"
But where do I now find this saved mapping to run this again?
Sorry very new to CIVICRM and not a techie

Answer (score 2):

The next time you export participants, on step 2 of 3 choose "Select fields for export". A drop-down list should appear, labelled "Use Saved Field Mapping", where you can select the mapping that you previously saved.

Comment: That's what I was hoping but if I go back through Find Participant from the Event dashboard the option to select my saved mappings does not present itself

Comment: I have tried again and this time it has worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds as though something has gone amiss - perhaps the mapping failed to save or a JavaScript error is preventing the drop-down from appearing when you click "Select fields for export". Any errors in your browser console? What CiviCRM version are you using and which CMS? I tested on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/search?reset=1 and it worked correctly there, does it for you too?

Comment: Ah, messages crossed in the ether! Glad it's working for you now. In that case it helps to keep StackExchange happy if you up-vote and accept the answer.

Comment: @RichW Please don't forget to upvote and mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem!  This helps others with the same problem in the future.